# Replication for local and global databases

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-connection, replication

I have a server which is running a large database. Many computers and laptops will connect to my server and download this large database to run in localhost. They will create, modify or delete this local database. When everything is done, these databases need to be synchronized to the main database on the server.

I am using PostgreSQL, by the way.

Here I come up with a solution using replication. [rubyrep](http://www.rubyrep.org/) is my choice. However, `rubyrep` requires every local database to have a global IP. I cannot find a way for my server to connect to those local databases. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: imagine computer A gets copy of db, renames table T to T1 and creates different table T (with different columns and data), computer B gets copy and loads much data to old table T, then both try to sync changes with you server db.

Comment: Those computers are trustworthy and I can guarantee that they will not change the name of any table or do anything harmful.